# is reversing an MD5 hash of password very effective?

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, cryptography

basically,

```
$stored_hash = strrev(md5($plain_text));
```

Because, now rainbow tables and pre-computed attacks might get a  hit on the hash, but when the attacker types in the calculated plain text, it will not authorize because the orginal hash is computed differently.

can i implement this on my app?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. It'd still be vulnerable to dictionary attacks

Comment: Reverseing an MD5 hash of password isn't possible.... but it is possible to find a value that generates the same md5 hash

Comment: What is the question: The title or if can be implemented?

Comment: @MarkBaker reversing the string

Comment: @wolfgang - rather than trusting to that form of obsucity, use a salt with your hashes (preferably a different salt for every user account), and use a stronger hashing algorithm.... better yet, use PHP's built-in [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: It's not useful. See [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Comment: you shouldn't be using md5 for any kind of secure hashing encryption, its only usecase is if you want to create a temporary hash string for a confirmation variable, like password reset or something because its quick.  you should be using a time-based hashing algo for secure things.

Comment: to expand on that: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php, and https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat for compatibility with older versions.

Comment: Note too that two identical passwords would show up as the same value as no salt is present. Just reversing an MD5 does not make it significantly better or worse than just MD5.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use MD5 for hashing passwords; even though certain "tricks" may make it harder to reverse engineer passwords, rainbow tables for reversed passwords may already exist, and if they don't they can be generated.

See [this article from PHP on the issue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash%20%27%27Why%20are%20common%20hashing%20functions%20such%20as%20md5%28%29%20and%20sha1%28%29%20unsuitable%20for%20passwords?%27%27). Essentially it boils down to that you should use [password hashing functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php%20%27%27Password%20Hashing%20Functions%27%27) that are provided by PHP. Using these has the additional advantage that, when you run your application on a future version of PHP, it may use a more secure hashing algorithm than it does now.